# Convert base R commands into SQL statements

Tags: sql, r, database

I am looking for a package that makes it easy to treat RDBMS in the same way you would treat data frames by automatically translating base R commands into valid SQL statements. I know that there is the `dbplyr` package but I am not a big fan of the tidyverse.

Is there a solution available that converts base R into SQL?

Comment: `sqldf` does some similar stuff, though I fear it is unique to SQLite. Other than that, I think you're stuck ... that's not an easy thing to do. (I know, I've been maintaining an internal package that translates much of ANSI SQL into mssql, postgresql, and sqlite. And I know I'm missing quite a bit and hack some of the rest.)

Comment: @r2evans: Isn't it the other direction with `sqldf`: Manipulate R Data Frames Using SQL?

Comment: Yes, true, but it's the only other package that does any translation in either direction. I think the answer to your question is "no", perhaps even capital-N "No", since that's not a trivial thing to do, especially with all of the dialects of SQL (some of which come close to ANSI-compliant).

Comment: But yes, you're absolutely correct, my comment is focusing on the wrong direction of translation.